# enabling Hyper-v in Bios is required for docker to work

Tags: docker, hyper-v

Let's make it simple ok, 
my device ( windows 10 pro ) is supposed to support ( SLAT ) according to core-info tool 
but when I try running system info in me power-shell I see this

```
              VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
              Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
              Second Level Address Translation: No
              Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

then when I try to run Docker it's not launching and it shows that I must enable Virtualization in my BIOS

I 've tried all the traditional stuff like : 
1- in your PowerShell type 
    `dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All`
2- try to reboot your pc and make sure virtualization is enabled in BIOs setting (I did but it didn't solve my problem.
3- I tried to enable Hyper-v using windows features turn them on or off

I expect to be able to run docker

Comment: You can try Docker for Windows but instead of Hyper-V go for Virtual Box

Comment: first of all thanks for your speedy response. and I 'm gonna give it a try and I will share with you what happened with me.

Comment: @nivhty 
this toolbox ( Virtual Box ) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1c2fce69-368a-435e-83e6-ff1381fcb38b/the-processor-does-not-support-second-level-address-translation-slat?forum=winserverhyperv), that could be a processor issue.

> Second Level Address Translation (SLAT), also known as nested paging, is a hardware-assisted virtualization technology which makes it possible to avoid the overhead associated with software-managed shadow page tables.

The thread includes links to know if your processor supports the function of not.

Regarding [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), this is what the [legacy Docker Toolbox uses](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/).

If it is not working either, you could try and use (with VirtualBox 6.x) a nested virtualization approach, as [explained here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-windows-sandbox-in-virtualbox-guest-os), activating a Windows sandbox.

Comment: actually, my processor supports ( SLAT ) as mentioned above so I don't think it's a processor issue

Comment: @kyrolosmagdy "as mentioned above"? I see "Second Level Address Translation: No", so I don't know why https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo would report SLAT supported here (and coreinfo was last released in 2014...).